# Host our ASP.NET Core MVC is returning this error "403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, bluehost

I have developed a simple ASP.NET Core MVC web app which has this controller class and this view to show a PDF file:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

View:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title class="text-center"></title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="text-center">
    <a  href="~/file/MYCV.pdf">Click to view my CV</a></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now using Filezilla, I upload the files to our Bluehost provider, where the files got added on the root as follows:

[image]

but when I access the site, I get this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: What folder did you put the PDF in? Your source code says the folder name is "file" but I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: Wait - do you get this error when attempting to view the web page, or just when you attempt to access the PDF from the web page?

Comment: Did you load `HomeController.cs` to the `Controllers` folder, or somewhere else? It looks (in the image) as if it has no contents.

Comment: Umm, is this actually ASP.net hosting or did you go for php hosting by mistake and put your asp.net files in there? The second error is from apache afaik, not something you should get with asp.net.

Comment: @AnnL. the PDfis inside the wwwroot directory then there is afolder named file

Comment: @AnnL. both on the view and on the PDF i will get the same error

Comment: @AnnL. yes the HomeController is inside the Controllers folder

Comment: @jdweng i did not specify any https requirements.. also if i use https or http i will get the same error

Comment: @SpicyCatGames i am developing asp.net core,, which can be hosted inside Apache .. i  used filezilla to upload the code to the ftp server provided by bluehost

Comment: @JohnJohn Check out the configure Apache section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-2.2 (select your asp.net core version on the top left of the docs page first). Create the configuration file according to the doc page and that should solve your problem.

Comment: @SpicyCatGames i deployed the files inside the root (home directory )

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch hosting providers.  Bluehost does not support ASP.NET on shared servers or VMs.  It may be possible if you rent a dedicated server, but it'll probably save you time, energy and stress paying a little more to use Azure or a mid-market cloud provider that's slightly less expense - but has a business model with services and support engineers that fit your needs.

https://cheaperasp.net/bluehost-support-asp-net-ms-sql/

Comment: @JohnJohn - were you able to confirm Bluehost doesn't support Asp.net?  if so, it would be good of you to point others in need in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you uploaded all project files by FTP in ASP.NET Core you should publish assembly files after run publish command in Visual Studio or by wizard
Run this command to generate publish files `dotnet publish` in the package manager console after that you will find publish folder like this `bin\Debug\net6.0\publish` now you can use FTP or visual studio to deploy files to the host please follow the below link to more details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-aspnet-web-app?view=vs-2022&tabs=ftp-ftps

Or

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score -1):

Basically 403 forbidden error message happened when you haven't setup your own default page correctly. You may refer to this post https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/how-to-fix-403-forbidden-error-message/

Comment: The question is about asp.net core and your answer is about framework. Here's how to configure apache2 for asp.net core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Most important here is Blue doesn't support Asp.net. I believe he need to find .net hosting provider.